# Django bootstrap/middleware/enter-exit

Tags: python, django, request

I have following problem. I want to add to django some kind of setup/teardown for each request. For example at the beginning of per user request I want to collect start data collection and at the end of request dump all data to database (1).

What comes to my mind right now, at the start of middleware instantiate an object (like singleton), every other part of the code can import this object, use its methods and then same middleware before returning response will scrap the object. The only concern I have is to be a threadsafe, so maybe create a global dict, and register keys that are build upon url + session_id hash or maybe request object id (internal python object id, maybe is good way to go?). At the end of request key will be scrapped from dict.

Any recommendations, thoughts, ideas?

(1) Please do not ask me why I cannot access DB directly or anything like this. This is only an example. I'm looking for general idea for something like **enter** and **exit** but request-response wise that can be imported in any place in a code and safely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your middleware, you can create new object for data you want to maintain and put it in [`request.META`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) dict. It will be available wherever, `request` is available. In this case, I don't think you need to worry about thread-safety as each request will create new object.
2. If you want to just create data object once when request processing starts, destroy after processing the request and no other code references this data then you can look at [`request_started and request_finished`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_started) signals.

Comment: Signal is probably what I am looking for. I'll give it a shot and post update.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is very certainly not thread-safe. You should not store anything per-request either on the middleware object, or in the global namespace.

The usual way to do this is sort of thing to annotate it onto the request object. Middleware and views have access to this, but to get it anywhere else (eg in the model) you'll need to pass it around.